# Проблемы с кодировкой в CRUD приложении

Tags: java, кодировка, hibernate, spring-mvc

При добавлении информации с формы на русском языке в БД высвечиваются непонятные символы

```
ÐÐ¾Ð³Ð¾Ð»Ñ ÐÐ¸ÐºÐ¾Ð»Ð°Ð¹ ÐÐ°ÑÐ¸Ð»ÑÐµÐ²Ð¸Ñ
```

как это исправить? Технологии Spring MVC, hibernate, tomcat 8, MySQL
Вот контролер

```
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("book")Book book, HttpServletRequest request){
        bookService.addBookWithAuthor(book, request.getParameter("author_name"), request.getParameter("author_years"));
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

И сам метод

```
    @Override
    public void addBookWithAuthor(Book book, String author_name, String author_years) {
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setName(author_name);
        author.setYears(author_years);
        authorDao.saveAuthor(author);
        book.setAuthor(author);
        bookDao.addBook(book);
    }
```

Форма

```
<form name="book" action="/add" method="post">
    <p>Title</p>
    <input title="Title" type="text" name="title">
    <p>Price</p>
    <input title="Price" type="text" name="price">
    <p>Author name</p>
    <input title="Author_name" type="text" name="author_name">
    <p>Author years</p>
    <input title="Author_years" type="text" name="author_years">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Comment: На метод `add` приходит в нормальной кодировке? Или уже иероглифы?

Comment: меня смущает `request.getParameter("author_name")` попробуйте сначала вызвать `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` , а потом уже получение параметров. А так вопрос не полный, какую БД используете, на чем запускаете приложение, какие конфиги спринга для кодировки?

Comment: Зачем там вообще `request.getParameter()`?

Comment: @Chubatiy да, в метод add уже приходят иероглифы

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я получаю с формы объект book и имя и годы жизни автора, чтобы его создать и засетать книге по связи ManyToOne

Comment: Посмотрите пож. ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941751/html-form-does-not-send-utf-8-format-inputs